# How to ignore taps on Accessories using modern UICollectionViewListCell + UIListContentConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiaccessoryview, uicollectionviewlistcell

I want to ignore all taps on cell’s accessory views.

The cells of my collection view are plain cells from type `UICollectionViewListCell` (no subclass).  I am using `UIListContentConfiguration` and update the cell’s data within `UICollectionView.CellRegistration`.

My cells are also displaying `UIAccessories` (custom view) on the trailing edge. The accessories should only have decoration purposes (to display checkboxes).

```swift
extension UICellAccessory {
    static func checkmarkView(state: UIImage.CheckboxState) -> UICellAccessory {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.checkbox(state: state))
        let configuration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration.init(
            customView: imageView,
            placement: .trailing()
        )
         // imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // has no effect
        let accessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: configuration)
        return accessory
    }
}
```

As stated in the comment setting UIImageView’s `isUserInteractionEnabled` somehow has no effect.

My UICollectionView looks like this:

```swift
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
   let layout = makeLayout()
   let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
   collectionView.delegate = self
   collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false
   return collectionView
}()
```

UICollectionView’s have `isMultiSelectionEnabled` disabled by default in case that matters.

When tapping the cell’s contentView it behaves as expected. It triggers the delegate’s `didSelectItemAt`-method like I have implemented countless times.

But when tapping the cell’s accessory view, it’s behaviour is somewhat unexpected:

#### Observations:

If the cell is **not selected:**

- Tap on accessory invokes `didHighlightItemAt`. When setting a breakpoint here the cell is not visually highlighted at this point (what I would expect given the delegate-method’s name).
- The cell does highlight the cell after leaving this method.
- The method does not trigger `didSelectItemAt`.

If the cell is **selected**:

- Tap on the accessory invokes `didHighlightItemAt` and
- triggers `didSelectItemAt` after.

#### What I want to achieve:

A tap on a cell should:

1. Update the datamodel (selecting the item).
2. The cell should highlight for a short moment
3. The checkbox should reflect the item’s selection state.